# Flutter: How to hide or show more text within certain length

Tags: flutter, dart, text

My Container having a description of movies.

Initially, I want to show only a few lines of description. And below that there should be a link (**more...**), After Tapping **more...** all content of description should be get displayed.

For example, check this [JQuery plugin](https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Read-More-Less-Plugin-jQuery-Shorten/).

Comment: Hi you can use this https://medium.com/@VasyaFromRussia/expanding-text-in-flutter-92736226ace5

Answer (score 72):

you can do that this way

[image: example]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:meta/meta.dart';

void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: new HomeScreen(),
    );
  }
}

class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  final String description =
      "Flutter is Google’s mobile UI framework for crafting high-quality native interfaces on iOS and Android in record time. Flutter works with existing code, is used by developers and organizations around the world, and is free and open source.";

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: const Text("Demo App"),
      ),
      body: new Container(
        child: new DescriptionTextWidget(text: description),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class DescriptionTextWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  final String text;

  DescriptionTextWidget({@required this.text});

  @override
  _DescriptionTextWidgetState createState() => new _DescriptionTextWidgetState();
}

class _DescriptionTextWidgetState extends State<DescriptionTextWidget> {
  String firstHalf;
  String secondHalf;

  bool flag = true;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    if (widget.text.length > 50) {
      firstHalf = widget.text.substring(0, 50);
      secondHalf = widget.text.substring(50, widget.text.length);
    } else {
      firstHalf = widget.text;
      secondHalf = "";
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Container(
      padding: new EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10.0, vertical: 10.0),
      child: secondHalf.isEmpty
          ? new Text(firstHalf)
          : new Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                new Text(flag ? (firstHalf + "...") : (firstHalf + secondHalf)),
                new InkWell(
                  child: new Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      new Text(
                        flag ? "show more" : "show less",
                        style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.blue),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  onTap: () {
                    setState(() {
                      flag = !flag;
                    });
                  },
                ),
              ],
            ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I have a question , how can I put the "show more" behind the text , I mean it looks like this "Flutter is Google’s mobile UI framework for... show more",they are both in the same line.

Comment: @JDNew Well, you could just simply add a row and wrap the `Text` & `InkWell` widget inside it. Or the most easiest way, is just rename the `Column` widget into `Row` widget. Give it a try. Let me know if you need another help.

Comment: is there any way to put icons instead of `Show more` and `Show less` ?

Comment: @RichiePermana renaming ```Column``` widget to a ```Row``` widget gives an overflow error and even when replaced it with the ```Wrap``` widget it gives unexpected output

Comment: Perfect answer... Thanks buddy

Comment: What to do if the text is HTML?

Comment: @dqureshiumar Use `  InkWell(child: Icon(Icons.more_horiz_rounded),onTap: (){
                 setState(() {
                        flag = !flag;
                      });
               },)` or ` IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.more_horiz_rounded),onPressed: (){
                 setState(() {
                        flag = !flag;
                      });
               },)`

Answer (score 38):

To get Exact Behavior like JQuery plugin. you need to use `TextPainter` and calculate the hight on given Width.

[Expanded State](https://i.stack.imgur.com/viCoQ.png)

[Normal State](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XE3MK.png)

```
import 'package:flutter/gestures.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';

void main() => runApp(MaterialApp( home: DemoApp()));

class DemoApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(
            'Read More Text',
          )),
      body:  SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: <Widget>[
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                child: ExpandableText(
                  'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque scelerisque efficitur posuere. Curabitur tincidunt placerat diam ac efficitur. Cras rutrum egestas nisl vitae pulvinar. Donec id mollis diam, id hendrerit neque. Donec accumsan efficitur libero, vitae feugiat odio fringilla ac. Aliquam a turpis bibendum, varius erat dictum, feugiat libero. Nam et dignissim nibh. Morbi elementum varius elit, at dignissim ex accumsan a',
                   trimLines: 2,
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
    );
  }
}
class ExpandableText extends StatefulWidget {
  const ExpandableText(
      this.text, {
        Key key,
        this.trimLines = 2,
      })  : assert(text != null),
        super(key: key);

  final String text;
  final int trimLines;

  @override
  ExpandableTextState createState() => ExpandableTextState();
}

class ExpandableTextState extends State<ExpandableText> {
  bool _readMore = true;
  void _onTapLink() {
    setState(() => _readMore = !_readMore);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final DefaultTextStyle defaultTextStyle = DefaultTextStyle.of(context);
    final colorClickableText = Colors.blue;
    final widgetColor = Colors.black;
    TextSpan link = TextSpan(
      text: _readMore ? "... read more" : " read less",
      style: TextStyle(
        color: colorClickableText,
      ),
      recognizer: TapGestureRecognizer()..onTap = _onTapLink
    );
    Widget result = LayoutBuilder(
      builder: (BuildContext context, BoxConstraints constraints) {
        assert(constraints.hasBoundedWidth);
        final double maxWidth = constraints.maxWidth;
        // Create a TextSpan with data
        final text = TextSpan(
          text: widget.text,
        );
        // Layout and measure link
        TextPainter textPainter = TextPainter(
          text: link,
          textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,//better to pass this from master widget if ltr and rtl both supported
          maxLines: widget.trimLines,
          ellipsis: '...',
        );
        textPainter.layout(minWidth: constraints.minWidth, maxWidth: maxWidth);
        final linkSize = textPainter.size;
        // Layout and measure text
        textPainter.text = text;
        textPainter.layout(minWidth: constraints.minWidth, maxWidth: maxWidth);
        final textSize = textPainter.size;
        // Get the endIndex of data
        int endIndex;
        final pos = textPainter.getPositionForOffset(Offset(
            textSize.width - linkSize.width,
            textSize.height,
        ));
        endIndex = textPainter.getOffsetBefore(pos.offset);
        var textSpan;
        if (textPainter.didExceedMaxLines) {
          textSpan = TextSpan(
            text: _readMore
                ? widget.text.substring(0, endIndex)
                : widget.text,
            style: TextStyle(
              color: widgetColor,
            ),
            children: <TextSpan>[link],
          );
        } else {
          textSpan = TextSpan(
            text: widget.text,
          );
        }
        return RichText(
          softWrap: true,
          overflow: TextOverflow.clip,
          text: textSpan,
        );
      },
    );
    return result;
  }
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to add icons instead of `read more` ?

Comment: Thanks for the help. Works perfectly!

Comment: Lines that are not trimmed return blank.

Comment: its funny how you take the code from the [readmore](https://pub.dev/packages/readmore) package and change the class name to ExpendableText.. I think its better if you just answer with "refer this package" instead of copy the code from the package itself... very funny..

Comment: @BurakMeteErdoğan Add color to the text span when the text doesn't exceed the limir.

Answer (score 33):

A simple example

```
class ExpandableText extends StatefulWidget {
  ExpandableText(this.text);

  final String text;
  bool isExpanded = false;

  @override
  _ExpandableTextState createState() => new _ExpandableTextState();
}

class _ExpandableTextState extends State<ExpandableText> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Column(children: <Widget>[
      new ConstrainedBox(
          constraints: widget.isExpanded
              ? new BoxConstraints()
              : new BoxConstraints(maxHeight: 50.0),
          child: new Text(
            widget.text,
            softWrap: true,
            overflow: TextOverflow.fade,
          )),
      widget.isExpanded
          ? new Container()
          : new FlatButton(
              child: const Text('...'),
              onPressed: () => setState(() => widget.isExpanded = true))
    ]);
  }
}
```

with animation

```
class ExpandableText extends StatefulWidget {
  ExpandableText(this.text);

  final String text;
  bool isExpanded = false;

  @override
  _ExpandableTextState createState() => new _ExpandableTextState();
}

class _ExpandableTextState extends State<ExpandableText>
    with TickerProviderStateMixin<ExpandableText> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Column(children: <Widget>[
      new AnimatedSize(
          vsync: this,
          duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
          child: new ConstrainedBox(
              constraints: widget.isExpanded
                  ? new BoxConstraints()
                  : new BoxConstraints(maxHeight: 50.0),
              child: new Text(
                widget.text,
                softWrap: true,
                overflow: TextOverflow.fade,
              ))),
      widget.isExpanded
          ? new ConstrainedBox(constraints: new BoxConstraints())
          : new FlatButton(
          child: const Text('...'),
          onPressed: () => setState(() => widget.isExpanded = true))
    ]);
  }
}
```

Comment: this work for me amongst others while working with non text content... kudos

Comment: Good job, this code simply can extends to collapsing,:

          widget.isExpanded
          ? new FlatButton(
          child: const Text('less ...'),
          onPressed: () => setState(() => widget.isExpanded = flase))
          : new FlatButton(
          child: const Text('more...'),
          onPressed: () => setState(() => widget.isExpanded = true))

Answer (score 13):

If you want to just use a **package** to simply do it, you can use the [Readmore](https://pub.dev/packages/readmore) package. its working just fine and so simple to use.

```
import 'package:readmore/readmore.dart';

ReadMoreText(
  'Flutter is Google’s mobile UI open source framework to build high-quality native (super fast) interfaces for iOS and Android apps with the unified codebase.',
  trimLines: 2,
  colorClickableText: Colors.pink,
  trimMode: TrimMode.Line,
  trimCollapsedText: 'Show more',
  trimExpandedText: 'Show less',
  moreStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 14, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
);
```

Comment: awesome package

Answer (score 10):

**Try this.**

Watch the output from [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1aNYl43sOU-P-ShPDnR8sTx_HsjyyW54B)  ( Video )

or refer below images

[image]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class DemoPage extends StatefulWidget {
  final Widget child;

  DemoPage({Key key, this.child}) : super(key: key);

  _DemoPageState createState() => _DemoPageState();
}

class _DemoPageState extends State<DemoPage> {

String descText = "Description Line 1\nDescription Line 2\nDescription Line 3\nDescription Line 4\nDescription Line 5\nDescription Line 6\nDescription Line 7\nDescription Line 8";
bool descTextShowFlag = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("DemoPage"),
      ),
      body: new Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
        child: new Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[
              Text(descText,
                maxLines: descTextShowFlag ? 8 : 2,textAlign: TextAlign.start),
              InkWell(
                onTap: (){ setState(() {
                descTextShowFlag = !descTextShowFlag; 
                }); },
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    descTextShowFlag ? Text("Show Less",style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue),) :  Text("Show More",style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue))
                  ],
                ),
              ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: i implemented youre example, but 'show more' button not working, when tap on it

Comment: @MarinaVoronova is there any error you are getting? check whether you are changing value of variable and setting `setState()` method or not

Comment: How would you set as wrap-content in case of expanded state.

Comment: @KiranBablani here In this code we are changing state using `show more` and `show less` links, to change the state just hit the method they are calling

Answer (score 4):

Please use package flutter-expandable. 
 
This package can produce an effect of expanding an image or text. 
https://github.com/aryzhov/flutter-expandable

[image]

```
import 'package:expandable/expandable.dart';
...
ExpandablePanel(
        header: Text( content,
          maxLines: 2,
          style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.body2,
        ),
        expanded: Align(
            alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
            child: Text(
              content,
              softWrap: true,
            )),
        tapHeaderToExpand: true,
        hasIcon: true,
      ),
```

Answer (score 3):

ExpandableText with regrex validation as well.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart';

class ExpandableText extends StatefulWidget {
  ExpandableText(this.text);

  final String text;
  // bool isExpanded = false;

  @override
  _ExpandableTextState createState() => new _ExpandableTextState();
}

class _ExpandableTextState extends State<ExpandableText> {
  String text;
  bool canExpand = false;
  bool isExpand = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    //
    canExpand = widget.text != null && widget.text.length >= 150;
    text = canExpand
        ? (isExpand ? widget.text : widget.text.substring(0, 150))
        : (widget.text);

    return canExpand
        ? Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: <Widget>[
              buildTextWithLinks(text.trim()),
              GestureDetector(
                onTap: () {
                  setState(() {
                    isExpand = !isExpand;
                  });
                },
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 4.0),
                  child: Text(isExpand ? ' ... show less' : ' ... show more'
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          )
        : Text(text != null ? text : "");
  }
}

Text buildTextWithLinks(String textToLink, {String text}) =>
    Text.rich(TextSpan(children: linkify(textToLink)));

Future<void> openUrl(String url) async {
  if (await canLaunch(url)) {
    await launch(url);
  } else {
    throw 'Could not launch $url';
  }
}

const String urlPattern =
    r"(https?|http)://([-A-Z0-9.]+)(/[-A-Z0-9+&@#/%=~_|!:,.;]*)?(\?[A-Z0-9+&@#/%=~_|!:‌​,.;]*)?";
const String emailPattern = r'\S+@\S+';
const String phonePattern = r'[\d-]{9,}';
final RegExp linkRegExp = RegExp(
    '($urlPattern)|($emailPattern)|($phonePattern)',
    caseSensitive: false);

WidgetSpan buildLinkComponent(String text, String linkToOpen) => WidgetSpan(
        child: InkWell(
      child: Text(
        text,
        style: TextStyle(
          color: Colors.red,
          decoration: TextDecoration.underline,
        ),
      ),
      onTap: () => openUrl(linkToOpen),
    ));

List<InlineSpan> linkify(String text) {
  final List<InlineSpan> list = <InlineSpan>[];
  final RegExpMatch match = linkRegExp.firstMatch(text);
  if (match == null) {
    list.add(TextSpan(text: text));
    return list;
  }

  if (match.start > 0) {
    list.add(TextSpan(text: text.substring(0, match.start)));
  }

  final String linkText = match.group(0);
  if (linkText.contains(RegExp(urlPattern, caseSensitive: false))) {
    list.add(buildLinkComponent(linkText, linkText));
  } else if (linkText.contains(RegExp(emailPattern, caseSensitive: false))) {
    list.add(buildLinkComponent(linkText, 'mailto:$linkText'));
  } else if (linkText.contains(RegExp(phonePattern, caseSensitive: false))) {
    list.add(buildLinkComponent(linkText, 'tel:$linkText'));
  } else {
    throw 'Unexpected match: $linkText';
  }

  list.addAll(linkify(text.substring(match.start + linkText.length)));

  return list;
}
```

Comment: Beautiful! This is what I was looking for. Expandable plus Clickable. Great!

Answer (score 3):

This an old question, but hope this could help anybody who looks for simple fast solution with simple code:
Just check if the text less than (for example) 125 chars, then show the whole text, if not show the first 125 chars then use '... show more' as textspan where when you click on it show the whole text and change 'show more' with 'show less'

I am using here getx for state mang, if you are not using it just use statefull screen with setstate to change its value

```
final RxBool showLongDes = false.obs;
final String shortDescription = 'This is great product ...'
...

shortDescription.length <= 125

? Text(shortDescription)      
:Obx(() {
   return RichText(
       text: TextSpan(
         text: showLongDes.value
               ?shortDescription
                : shortDescription.substring(0, 125) + ' ... '
          children: [
             TextSpan(
                 text: showLongDes.value
                        ? ' ' + 'Show less'
                        : 'Show more',
                 recognizer: TapGestureRecognizer()
                       ..onTap = () => showLongDes.value =!showLongDes.value,
                 style: GoogleFonts.rubik(
                          color: Colors.blue,
                            decoration: TextDecoration.underline),
             )
          ],
       ),
);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Widget _text() {
var exceeded;
return LayoutBuilder(builder: (context, size) {
  // Build the textspan
  var span = TextSpan(
    text:
        "The red-tailed tropicbird is a seabird native to the tropical Indian and Pacific Oceans. One of three closely related species of tropicbird, it has four subspecies. Text wrapping is quite a pain for me too. I find that putting Text in a Container and then wrapping that container in a Expanded/Flexible works well.",
    style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.body1.copyWith(color: Colors.white),
  );

  // Use a textpainter to determine if it will exceed max lines
  var tp = TextPainter(
    maxLines: _maxLine.toInt(),
    textAlign: TextAlign.left,
    textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
    text: span,
  );

  // trigger it to layout
  tp.layout(maxWidth: size.maxWidth);

  // whether the text overflowed or not
  exceeded = tp.didExceedMaxLines;

  // return Column(children: <Widget>[
  return Container(
    child: exceeded && seeMoreClicked
        ? _seeMoreLess(span, "See Less ")
        : exceeded && !seeMoreClicked
            ? _seeMoreLess(span, "See More", 3)
            : Text.rich(
                span,
                overflow: TextOverflow.visible,
              ),
  );
});
}

Widget _seeMoreLess(TextSpan span, String _text, [int maxLine = 0]) {
return Column(
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
  children: <Widget>[
    maxLine > 0
        ? Text.rich(
            span,
            overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
            maxLines: 3,
          )
        : Text.rich(
            span,
            overflow: TextOverflow.visible,
          ),
    InkWell(
        child: Text(
          _text,
          style: Theme.of(context)
              .textTheme
              .body1
              .copyWith(color: Colors.blue),
        ),
        onTap: () {
          setState(() {
            seeMoreClicked = !seeMoreClicked;
          });
        }),
  ],
);
```

Answer (score 1):

**Option 1:**
if you are looking for something like facebook,Linkedin you just need one variable isOpen. If isOpen true return MoreText else LessText **(use substring)** .
May not be a perfect solution but you can get what you need

**Warning!!! you have to handle text length when using substring**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:linky/presentation/extension/utils.dart';

class ExpandableText extends StatefulWidget {
  final String text;
  final double max;
  const ExpandableText({Key? key, required this.text, required this.max})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ExpandableTextState createState() => _ExpandableTextState();
}

class _ExpandableTextState extends State<ExpandableText> {
  TextPainter? textPainter;
  bool isOpen = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return isOpen
        ? SizedBox(
            child: Align(
                alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                child: RichText(
                  textAlign: TextAlign.start,
                  text: TextSpan(children: [
                    TextSpan(
                        text: widget.text, style: textTheme(context).bodyText1),
                    WidgetSpan(
                        child: InkWell(
                            onTap: () {
                              setState(() {
                                isOpen = !isOpen;
                              });
                            },
                            child: Text(
                              "Less more",
                              style: textTheme(context).bodyText1!.copyWith(
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                  color: Colors.blueAccent),
                            )),
                        style: textTheme(context).bodyText1)
                  ]),
                )))
        : Align(
            alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
            child: RichText(
              textAlign: TextAlign.start,
              maxLines: 2,
              text: TextSpan(children: [
                TextSpan(
                    text: widget.text.substring(
                            0,
                            int.parse(
                                "${(widget.text.length * widget.max).toInt()}")) +
                        "...",
                    style: textTheme(context).bodyText1),
                WidgetSpan(
                    child: InkWell(
                        mouseCursor: SystemMouseCursors.click,
                        onTap: () {
                          setState(() {
                            isOpen = !isOpen;
                          });
                        },
                        child: Text(
                          "more",
                          style: textTheme(context).bodyText1!.copyWith(
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              color: Colors.blueAccent),
                        )),
                    style: textTheme(context).bodyText1)
              ]),
            ),
          );
  }
}
```

Exemple :

```
ExpandableText(
          text: users[0].loremIpsum,
          max: 0.2,
        )
```

**Option 2**: If you need something like ExpansionPanel you juste use widget **ExpansionTile** .

```
ExpansionTile(title: title,children: [])
```

Inside Childress moreText & title your LessText . You can hide LessText when isOpen

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
AnimatedCrossFade(
   duration: Duration(milliseconds: 100),
   firstChild: Text(
      "Short text",
      key: ValueKey<int>(0),
      overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
      maxLines: 2,
   ),
   secondChild: Text(
      "short text that can be longer",
      key: ValueKey<int>(1),
   ),
   crossFadeState: isVisible ? CrossFadeState.showFirst : CrossFadeState.showSecond,
),
SizedBox(
   height: 10,
),
Center(
   child: TextButton.icon(
   onPressed: () {
      setState(() {
         isVisible = !isVisible;
      });
    },
    icon: Text("View More"),
    label: Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_down),
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using maxLines on the text widget gives a clean and precise result. Change the reveal bool value when the user clicks on the text. Hope this helps someone.

```dart
class SingleReview extends StatefulWidget {
  const SingleReview({
    Key? key,
    required this.reviewText,
  }) : super(key: key);
  final String reviewText;
  @override
  State<SingleReview> createState() => _SingleReviewState();
}

class _SingleReviewState extends State<SingleReview> {
  bool reveal = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
        horizontal: 18.0,
        vertical: 10,
      ),
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
   
          InkWell(
            onTap: () {
              setState(() {
                reveal = !reveal;
              });
            },
            child: Text(
              widget.reviewText,
              maxLines: reveal ? 2 : null,
              overflow: reveal ? TextOverflow.ellipsis : null,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Easily by using a bool:

> open

var with default value = false,

**Then**, create a button to-->

```
 setState(() {
   open = !open;
 });
```

**After That**,

```
open == true
     ? Text(
         des,//your long text. in hidden mode
         style: TextStyle(color: black),
         maxLines: 3,//by controlling the no. lines will appear
         overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,//shape of disappeared txt
       )
     : Text(
         des,//your long text in normal view.
         style: TextStyle(color: black),
```

> in hidden

[image]

> in normal

[image]

Answer (score -1):

I examine all the answer and make a good solution. Just pass your text here and you can change number of lines just by changing maxLines in text widget..

```dart
class ExpandableText extends StatefulWidget {
  final String text;
  const ExpandableText(this.text, {Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ExpandableTextState createState() => _ExpandableTextState();
}

class _ExpandableTextState extends State<ExpandableText>
    with TickerProviderStateMixin<ExpandableText> {
  bool isExpanded = false;
  late int numLines;

 @override
 void initState() {
   numLines = '\n'.allMatches(widget.text).length + 1;
   super.initState();
 }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SizedBox(
      width: double.infinity,
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          AnimatedSize(
            duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 200),
            child: Text(
                widget.text,
                maxLines: isExpanded ? null : 3,
                softWrap: true,
                overflow: TextOverflow.fade,
              ),
          ),
         numLines > 2
          ? TextButton(
              child: const Text('View more'),
              onPressed: () => setState(() => 
                   isExpanded = !isExpanded),
            )
          : const SizedBox()
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

[1st screenshot Show less](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ld1ZQ.png)

[2nd screenshot Show more](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RgPeH.png)

[3rd screenshot When text length less than 197](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YICa0.png)

Code:

```
bool isExpanded = false;
Column(
                children: [
                  Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                    child: Text(
                      widget.title,
                      style: TextStyles.regularStyle.copyWith(
                        color: const Color(0xFF1A1A1A),
                      ),
                      maxLines: isExpanded ? 11 : 4,
                      softWrap: true,
                      // overflow: TextOverflow.fade,
                    ),
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(
                    height: 4,
                  ),
                  widget.title.length < 197
                      ? SizedBox()
                      : InkWell(
                          onTap: () {
                            setState(() {
                              isExpanded = !isExpanded;
                            });
                          },
                          child: Align(
                            alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                            child: Text(
                              isExpanded == false
                                  ? 'Показать полностью...'
                                  : 'Show less',
                              style: TextStyles.mediumStyle.copyWith(
                                fontSize: 14,
                                color: const Color(0xff3D3DD8),
                              ),
                              maxLines: 1,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                ],
              ),
```

[Code in pastebin](https://pastebin.com/8CLNt3Bb)

[Full code resources](https://pastebin.com/jbdJGWwT)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).