# How expand text and container according text size?

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm trying to create a card with a text within a container but I would like to show only a part of the text and when the user click on "show more", show the rest. I saw a Widget to construct text like this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49577276/6776511), but I need expand the card container either and I don't know how to do that because I need to know how many lines the text have to expand with the correctly size. Exists a way to calculate the size according the number of lines or characters?

I tried to create the card as follows, where the `DescriptionText` is the Widget on the link and specify a minHeight in the Container in the hope of expanding the container along with the text but did not work.

```
Widget _showAnswerCard(Answer answer, User user) {
    return Card(
        elevation: 3.0,
        color: Theme.of(context).backgroundColor,
        child: Container(
          constraints: BoxConstraints(minHeight: 90),
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
          child: Flex(
            direction: Axis.horizontal,
            children: <Widget>[
              Expanded(flex: 1, child: _showUserAvatar(answer)),
              Expanded(flex: 3, child: _showAnswerDetails(answer, user)),
            ],
          ),
        ));
  }

  Widget _showAnswerDetails(Answer answer, User user) {
    return Flex(
      direction: Axis.vertical,
      children: <Widget>[
        Expanded(
          flex: 3,
          child: DescriptionTextWidget(text: answer.content),
        ),
        Expanded(
          flex: 1,
          child: _showAnswerOptions(),
        )
      ],
    );
  }
```

I'll really appreciate if someone could help me with that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use [`Wrap`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Wrap-class.html) widget to wrap your Card widget.

Based on your [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49572747/flutter-how-to-hide-or-show-more-text-within-certain-length/49577276#49577276) for suggested answer. I did change to use `Wrap` widget.

Jus do copy/paste below code and check.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ProductDetailPage extends StatelessWidget {
  final String description =
      "Flutter is Google’s mobile UI framework for crafting high-quality native interfaces on iOS and Android in record time. Flutter works with existing code, is used by developers and organizations around the world, and is free and open source.";

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: const Text("Demo App"),
      ),
      body: new Container(
        child: new DescriptionTextWidget(text: description),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class DescriptionTextWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  final String text;

  DescriptionTextWidget({@required this.text});

  @override
  _DescriptionTextWidgetState createState() =>
      new _DescriptionTextWidgetState();
}

class _DescriptionTextWidgetState extends State<DescriptionTextWidget> {
  bool flag = true;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Wrap(
      children: <Widget>[
        Card(
          margin: EdgeInsets.all(8),
          child: Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10.0, vertical: 10.0),
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Container(
                    child: Text(
                      widget.text,
                      overflow: flag ? TextOverflow.ellipsis : null,
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 15,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  InkWell(
                    child: Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Text(
                          flag ? "show more" : "show less",
                          style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.blue),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                    onTap: () {
                      setState(() {
                        flag = !flag;
                      });
                    },
                  ),
                ],
              )),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: OMG thanks! I didn't know this Widget, you really saved my life

Comment: Correct link to Wrap class: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Wrap-class.html

Answer (score 0):

The solution I can think of is to use two labels, one for displaying only one line of text and one for displaying all the text. When the button is clicked, the two labels are alternately displayed in an animated manner. There is no computer at the moment, it is not convenient to verify, I hope to give you some help in the implementation of the program.