# Flutter - How to show button when container height is bigger than number

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm building a `ListView` with dynamic text in each item. But I want to cap the maximum height of each item and show a 'More' button when the height is bigger than something.

I currently have this in the item:

```dart
Container(
    constraints: BoxConstraints(maxHeight: 300),
    child: Text(htmlContent),
)
```

Which is capping the height as expected. But how can I display the `More` button on the items that do have the height larger than 300?

I can't just check the length of the string `htmlContent` because it has HTML tags which make the height variable depending on the tag type. That's why I need to check height somehow

Comment: Maybe you can use [ExpansionTile](https://flutter.dev/docs/catalog/samples/expansion-tile-sample) instead.

Comment: hey @JRamos29 looks like the expansion tile always has 2 states. Which is not what I need. If the height is < 300, there shouldn't be 2 states. Plus I can't seem to change the button for changing the states (the arrow)

Comment: I noticed you are using an Html widget as child. How can you get the height of this widget to know if it's greater than 300? There's someway to get the height from html's `body` that you are setting as content?

Comment: It would be exactly the same if it were a Text widget. The point is that content is dynamic. Instead of dynamic html ti would be dynamic text.

Comment: I change Html to Text to avoid confusion

Comment: Well, if the content will always be just String, as workaround you can add some dummy text to check the length of the String that fits the height of 300, then define that length as maximum, and for the length greater than that you add a button. Isn't the most elegant way to do it, but maybe it works.

Comment: How would I know how much text is equal to 300 height? This is running in different phones/tablets. So a string that is 100 characters in a tablet might be just one line, but on an iPhone SE it's 5 lines. So I can't rely on text length. I need to know widget height

Comment: Oh, sorry. But i found this [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49572747/flutter-how-to-hide-or-show-more-text-within-certain-length). Maybe some of the proposed solutions can help you.

Comment: Thank you @JRamos29 that would work if my content was plain text. But the content is HTML, and I can't just cut it anywhere because it would break the HTML tags... or if the content at the beginning is an image url, it could break the url midway. I guess I should cange the tag back to Html instead of text, to make this clear. But the concept is the same.

Comment: Since you want to show a html content, you can use a regex or a html parser to get the content inside of the tags with useful content like head, tittle, body, etc. and display them like plain text in the list item. If the length is greater than a given number of characters, you can show a button `More` to show the full content in html format.

Answer (score 0):

ListView needs a constrained height. You provide a hight to the listView by wrapping it in a container or keep the listView in Expanded widget for taking available height.

Comment: My question is not about the ListView itself but about its items

Answer (score 0):

Use `LayoutBuilder` it will give you what constraints are available for the descendants through a `BoxConstraints` as a second parameter to the builder function

```
LayoutBuilder(
 builder: (ctx,constraints){
      if(constraints.maxHeight>300){
        return Widget //accordingly;
      } else {
        return Widget //accordingly
      }
    }
 )
```

Comment: constraints.maxHeight is always returning infinity

Comment: try to wrap LayoutBuilder in Expanded

Comment: Doing that breaks the layout with this error `RenderFlex children have non-zero flex but incoming height constraints are unbounded.`

Comment: try to wrap them in Flexible and set the flex property rather than wrapping in Expanded