# Flutter - Put the expand arrow at the end of the last line of the text

Tags: flutter, dart

Basically I want to achieve the similar thing as this post [Flutter: How to hide or show more text within certain length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49572747/flutter-how-to-hide-or-show-more-text-within-certain-length). However, I need to replace "show more" with an arrow and the arrow should be at the end of the last line of the collapsed text (not below it). I checked https://pub.dev/packages/expand_widget and https://pub.dev/packages/expandable these two packages, but they didn't seem to satisfy my requirements.

Could anyone help me with it? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I think it should work for you!
>
> ```
> Row(
>   children: [
>     Expanded(
>       child: Text("your text or widget"),
>     ),
>     Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_down)
>   ],
> );
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Just have an arrorw_down icon. When clicked change a boolean in setState(). In the widget tree just check if it's true, show something, else don't.
Switch between arrow_up/down depending on the boolean.

```
Expanded(
      flex: 2,
      child: InkWell(
        onTap: () {
          setState(() {
            isBubbleExpanded = !isBubbleExpanded; // should expand?
          });
        },
        child: Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(3),
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment:
                MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Center(
                    child: Icon(isBubbleExpanded
                        ? Icons.keyboard_arrow_up
                        : Icons.keyboard_arrow_down),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ));
  }
```

Then somewhere else in the tree:

```
if (isBubbleExpanded)
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Expanded(
                    flex: 2,
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(2),
                      child: Center(),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    flex: 2,
                    child: Center(
                      child: IconButton(
                        icon: const Icon(CupertinoIcons.info),
                        onPressed: () {
                          Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(
                            SomeScreen.routeName,
                            arguments: widget.document,
                          );
                        },
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
```