# How to add show more and show less options for attributed text in Flutter App?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

In my application I need to show options for Show more and Show less for the attributed text. If there is the simple Text then I could manage the things by using `.subString` function for first few characters and full text.

But here in my case I am using `flutter_html` lib. Here if I take data using `.subString` then attributed text getting disturbed which creates wrong output.

For consideration my text is as mentioned below:

The system requirements are\r\n        :

  \r\n
- An internet connection – broadband wired or wireless (3G or 4G/LTE)
  \r\n
- Speakers and a microphone (required in case of interactive sessions) – Built-in, USB plug-in, or wireless Bluetooth
  \r\n
- A webcam or HD webcam - built-in, USB plug-in (required in case of interactive sessions)
  \r\n
- CLICK HERE to view the System Requirements for Zoom.
  \r\n

Consider the image as mentioned below:

[image]

Is there something else can be done here to achieve this feature without using .subString feature!!??

Answer (score 0):

Solution 1 :
You can try https://pub.dev/packages/readmore , this plugin.
A Flutter plugin that allow expand and collapse text.

Solution 2 :
[Flutter: How to hide or show more text within certain length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49572747/flutter-how-to-hide-or-show-more-text-within-certain-length)

Comment: I went through your response but https://pub.dev/packages/readmore doesn't support the attributed texts and for solution 2 they are using .subStrings to show and hide their content. Is there some thing else we can manage here!!??